# Does timestamp also change with nonce to calculate block hash in blockchain? How hash is calculated?

Tags: hash, blockchain, cryptocurrency

Do we need to update date timestamp on every hash calculation update? How it's implemented in most popular cryptocurrencies?

```js
function isValidHashDifficulty() {
  //validate calculated hash to fit requirements
}

function calculateHash(nextIndex, previousHash, timestamp, data, nonce) {
  //calculate hash
}
let nonce = 0;
let nextIndex, previousHash, data;

let timestamp = new Date().getTime(); // do we use this timestamp?

while (!isValidHashDifficulty(nextHash)) {
  nonce = nonce + 1;
  timestamp = new Date().getTime(); //or do we get new date on every calculation attempt?
  nextHash = calculateHash(nextIndex, previousHash, timestamp, data, nonce);
}
```

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you are asking in general, or how is this implemented in some established cryptocurrency, so I will try to answer from both sides.

At least when Bitcoin and Ethereum are explained from a theoretical point, only an increment to the nonce is mentioned. I am not familiar with their source code, but I would say that the timestamp is not always recomputed, as this would mean making a system call for each attempt to solve the Proof of Work puzzle, making the algorithm slower.

A similar remark is valid for your general case. You can recompute the timestamp, but you don't have to. This will not affect your probability of solving the puzzle. If you do recompute it, the algorithm will be slower, but the block will have a timestamp that is more accurate (to its exact mining time).

**UPDATE**:

I was unable to locate the exact place in the Bitcoin code base, but I am now certain that the timestamp does not change each time, since it would be a pretty meaningless operation that would just slow down the search for solution to the mining puzzle. The timestamps of blocks in the blockchain are not required to be in the strictly increasing order. This is due to the fact that the network is distributed throughout the world, and there is no designated time zone which is to be used for timestamps.

Basically, a timestamp just needs to be "not too old", or if you want it more precisely: **"a timestamp is accepted as valid if it is greater than the median timestamp of previous 11 blocks, and less than the network-adjusted time + 2 hours"**. For more details, here are some resources:

https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/915/why-dont-the-timestamps-in-the-block-chain-always-increase

https://medium.com/all-things-ledger/decoding-the-enigma-of-bitcoin-mining-f8b2697bc4e2

Now, it's hard to say for all popular cryptocurrencies, but at least Bitcoin, Ethereum and other ones whose mining process works in the same fashion do not increase the timestamp before every hash recalculation.